# java mvc with observable pattern

Tags: java, model-view-controller, observer-pattern

I have 3 classes whose names are representative and i intend to make this work in an mvc pattern.

The following are the classes

```
public class view  {

 static int n;
 static model Model=new model();
    public static void main(String args[]){

        Model.show(5);
        System.out.println("The value is "+n);
    }

}




public class model {

    public interface Observer{
        public void show(int n);
    }

    protected Observer observer;
    public void setObserver(Observer observer) {
        this.observer = observer;
    }

    public void show(int n)
    {
        System.out.println(n+1);
        observer.show(5);
    }


}



public class Logger implements model.Observer {

    private view View;

    public Logger(view View) {
        this.View= View;
    }

    public void show(int n)
    {
        View.n=n;
    }

}
```

I was expecting this to work in the following order

the view calls the model and the model in turn calls the observer and the observer sets the value of n in the view.
But it gives me a null pointer exception in the model when i am trying to call the observer.
Am i doing something wrong ??

Comment: What is the purpose of the Observer pattern here?

Comment: The professor said "write an Observer pattern" ;)

Comment: It is super hard to read your code when you do not follow java standards:

static model Model=new model();

should look like:

static Model model=new Model();

then you can make sense when you do model.show();

System.out works because System.out is a static object.

Comment: ha ha not coz the professor asked me to... I am learning how to get around with MVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setObserver` is never being called so `observer` is `null`.

```
public class view  {

  static int n;
  model Model;

  private View(){
     Logger logger = new Logger(this);
     Model = new model();
     Model.setObserver(logger);
  }

  private void doIt(){

    Model.show(5);
    System.out.println("The value is "+n);
  }

  public static void main(String args[]){
      new View().doIt();
  }
}
```

Comment: where should i set the setObserver ?? I am not sure where i should make the call

Comment: That is not an easy question to answer given your code. `Model` needs an instance of `Logger`, but `Logger` needs an instance of `View` and you don't have an instance of `View` since you are calling everything from a `static void main` method. Seems like you need to create an instance of `View`, create an instance of `Logger` passing the `View` instance, and create an instance of `Model` passing the `Logger` instance.

Comment: Thank you that was useful and i did something on similar lines and it worked too... thanks for your replies ...